# ASP.NET MVC6 - The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

My goal is to search by last name within a GET call that will be used on the back-end. I have Get() and Get(int id) working perfectly fine, though I have spent a while tring to get SearchByLastName(string name) working but cannot. Here is the function within my controller

```
// GET
[Route("api/member/byLastname/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult SearchByLastName(string id)
{
    var member = _context.Members.SingleOrDefault(m => m.LastName == id);

    if (member == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(member);
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why this doesn't work when the other Get functions do and the routes look correct here.

the call I am making in this situation would look something like this:
http://.../api/Member/byLastName/Smith

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi,
How is that not working? The method doesn't get called? The string is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow I spent over an hour trying to find an answer and I get one right after I post this question. Sorry for that. Anyways the answer is that it is convention to use the verb Get as prefix within the name. I changed mine to `GetLastName(string id)` and it works now

Comment: Alternatively, you can put the `[HttpGet]` attribute on your action method.

Comment: Is there no `[HttpGet]` attribute in MVC 6 anymore?

Comment: @vcsjones haha can't believe we just posted that at the same time :)

Comment: Read into a bit more, and yes, I could have done that. Thanks guys! :)

Comment: Please mark your question as answered so the community can stop stumbling upon this thinking it needs review still. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Route[""]` I recommend always using the verb, it's support routing, so instead of

```
[Route("api/member/byLastname/{id}")]
```

you can do

```
[HttpGet("api/member/byLastname/{id}")]
```

*`HttpGet` attribute is on `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` namespace*